# iOS: How to watch NSManagedObject attributes while debugging

Tags: ios, core-data, watch

As the title said, I want to debug some Core Data bugs. Instead of using `NSLog` everywhere in the code, is it possible to watch a entity's attributes in XCode 4's watch window? Like the "quick watch" tool in Entity Framework 4.0 of .NET.

Comment: i haven't dug into the internals of the core data storage, so don't know what object values you might be able to use gdb `watch`, but if you have implemented a custom object, you can implement the accessor of a particular attribute, using a `setPrimative<Value>:` bracketed with `willChangeValueForKey:@"<value>"`, and `didChangeValueForKey:` methods - then you have a standard method to set a breakpoint at

Comment: @bshirley: So I still need to change my code. Thank you any way, @TechZen's answer works just fine.

Comment: i misunderstood your meaning of "watch", not knowing .NET.  you just wanted to examine the object in the debugger, i thought you wanted the debugger to break execution when a value changed.  a much more complex prospect.  good luck.

Comment: See also this question and answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7145034/how-do-i-add-a-watch-or-inspect-in-xcode

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Any value that has a named variable assigned to it can be viewed in the debugger. In Xcode 4 it appears in the debugger's left column. If you select the variable, you can use the contextual menu option "Print to console" to have a detailed description printed to the debugger console. This is useful when examining managed objects as they often contain more info than the list of variables can cleanly display.

(See- Xcode 4 Transition Guide:[Control Program Execution in the Debug Area and Source Editor, Figure 5-9](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/Xcode4TransitionGuide/Debugging/Debugging.html)

In addition, you can issue any of the standard gdb commands from the command line in the debugger console. The most useful of the these commands is `po` which stands for `print object`. Say you have an object `myObject` that has a property `aProperty`. You could examine it directly by using:

```
po [myObject valueForKey:@"aProperty"]
```

If you create NSManagedObject subclasses, you also have the option of overriding the `description` method which allows you to produce custom descriptions of the object which will show up in `print to console` and the `po` command.

Comment: you saved my day once again! Thank you.

Comment: Still valid in 2015. Right - Click the object in debug pane and select print description of "variable". Works like a charm! Thanks

Comment: Hover over the reference name to see all its props...lol, jokes. This is Xcode we are talking about, not a proper IDE. It's 2020, and those instructions above are still the only valid methods.

Comment: Core Data entities show only one property inside: a reference to themselves. So you can click and click and click and you will see your entity nested ad infinitum. Thanks XCode for being so useful.