# How do I add a Watch or Inspect in Xcode?

Tags: objective-c, xcode

as in the title is there a way in Xcode to Add Watch or Inspect a code segment in Xcode

for example how can I see the result of [myObject aMethod] with actually stepping over or Stepping in.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In the debugger console, if you stop at a breakpoint you can type `po [myObject aMethod]` to see the return value (if it's not an `id` type return value, use `p ([return type here])[myObject aMethod]`).

You can also set a breakpoint action to print something out without pausing, just right click to edit the breakpoint:

[image]

Comment: The reason you want a watch is usually that you want to step through and see it change, though. In other words, you *want* the breakpoint to stop. If you just want a lot of values in the console you can NSLog. A breakpoint that looks like a breakpoint but doesn't break at that point can be very confusing. Not a criticism towards your answer, since the asker wants what Apple doesn't provide and Apple provides confusing non-standard features.

Answer (score 22):

To actually see the value change while you step through, you can right click the watch list of the debug area and choose "Add Expression..."

[image]